# Exception in Nested/Child SP

Tags: sql, sql-server

**The problem is on SQL Server 2008**

I have run into this unusual situation. The situation is like this. I have two separate SQL Server installations. Lets name them as

> 1. Installation-1
> 2. Installation-2

On Installation-1 lets say I have database called Database-1. And on Installation-2 I have other database called Database-2.

Database-1 has a SP called **Parent_SP**. Database-2 has two SPs called **Child_SP_1** and **Child_SP_2**.

Installation-2 has been added as a linked server on Installation-1. 
The **Parent_SP** on Database-1 calls **Child_SP_1** which in turn calls **Child_SP_2**.

Now what happens is if there is an exception/error in **Child_SP_1**. I am able to catch it. However if the exception is raised at **Child_SP_2.** The exception never gets caught in **Parent_SP**.

I have no idea why such a behavior. Logically any exception should be raised eventually to parent SP. Which is not happening.

I've been trying to debug and create different scenarios but so far no luck.

Is there any reason why it should not work ?

Comment: Is it SQL 2012? If yes, then you can try `THROW` statement in Child SPs.

Comment: Yes in SQL 2012. That means putting a try catch in all the child sps and when an exception is caught throw it so it eventually reaches the calling SP ?

Comment: Yes sort of exception bubbling. Actually irrespective of SQL version if you just put try catch in parent sp and not in child sps you can catch child sps' exceptions in parent sp.

Comment: Exactly thats what it should happen. However such is not the case. First I am using linked server so i wonder if it has anything to do with a linked server. However exceptions raised at direct child sp are being caught in parent SP however exception raised in child's child sp are not caught in parent SP.

Comment: Can you provide code we can look at?

Comment: I can try, thing is its confidential code so I will have to make my own SPs in a way they mimick the actual SPs. Might take a few hours before I am available to do this.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using SQL Server 2008 not 2012